# how to serialize all img tags with Jquery

Tags: jquery, image

How do I serialize all `<img>` tags in my `<div>`?

```
<div id='My_gallery_fades' >
   <img src='car_black.jpg' />
   <img src='car_yellow.jpg' />
   <img src='car_red.jpg' />
</div>
```

And after find all `<img>`s, show effect FadeIn & fadeOut (or slideUp & slide Down) for create one simple gallery.

Comment: i have make a very fast load (sample) gallery ,

Comment: What do you mean by "serialize `<img>` tags"?  Use `$('img', '#My_gallery_fades')` to get the images.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Have you tried some plugins? There are multiple lightweight easy-to-use plugins **specifically** made for that task.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `jQuery` cycle plugin, this might help you instead of writing a image gallery on your own.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/